# Convert from int to float, possible round up?

Tags: floating-point, integer, converters, c++builder

C++ conversion:

I recieve information from Hardware in this Form:

`x = 564` as `int`.

I have show this information in `float`:

`xFloat = 56.4` as `float`

If I do `x/10` I always get the wrong result:

> `56.5` instead of `56.4`.

Is this a **Round up problem** or is it possible that my hardware doesn´t deliver right information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code like this

```
int x = 564;
double num = x / 10.0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Please note that in C++ the default decimals are `double`.

You can also try to use these:

```
int x=564;
float f=(float)x/10;    //56.400002    
float f1=x/10.0;        //56.400002
float f11=x/10.0f;      //56.400002
double d=(double)x/10;  //56.400000
double d1=x/10.0;       //56.400000
```